# how to use Microsoft Video Capture Macros using C#

Tags: c#, video-capture

I want to make an Windows application using C#.NET in which I capture video from an attached webcam and store it into any location.

Can anybody give me pointers on how to get started/accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your using Winforms, then you need to use a component of DirectX called DirectShow to do this. You can see an example and download source code from [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7637/DirectX-Video-Stream-and-frame-capture).

If you are using WPF, you can see how this is done from [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/285964/WPF-Webcam-Control).

If you need a library that will work with both WPF and Winforms, try [this link](http://easywebcam.codeplex.com/)